# Text field returns null on second submission Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm working on a form that filters the results of records, there are 2 text fields that are mat-autocompletes and some checkboxes.

When Apply filter is clicked the value of the fields are inserted into objects and pushed to an array.

And then the form is reset

My situation is, that I don't want the objects to be populated when the fields are empty.

The first time is fine and it works as expected, however on the next iteration, I get "can't get trim of null" (using .trim() on the field)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
                          <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Organisation</mat-placeholder>
                          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="filterOrganisation" [matAutocomplete]="auto" value="">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelect()">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let organisation of filteredOrganisations | async" [value]="organisation.Name">
                            {{ organisation.Name }}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
                          <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Countires</mat-placeholder>
                          <input type="text" matInput formControlName="filterCountries" [matAutocomplete]="auto2" value="">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelect()">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async" [value]="country.Name">
                            {{ country.Name }}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>


                    </div>
                  </div>
```

TS:

```
applyUserFilters() {
    let filterCountries: Filter;
    let filterOrganisation: Filter
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 1
    let organisationField = this.filterForm.get('filterOrganisation');
    let countriesField = this.filterForm.get('filterCountries');
    console.log(countriesField.value == '');//Is false second time
    if (organisationField.value.trim() == '') {
      organisationField.setValue('')
    } else {
      filterOrganisation = {
        Value: this.filterForm.get('filterOrganisation').value,
        Operation: this.filterOperation,
        Property: 'Organisation'
      }
      this.filtersArray.push(filterOrganisation);
      console.log(this.filtersArray)
    }

    if (countriesField.value.trim() == '') {
      countriesField.setValue('')
    } else {
      filterCountries = {
        Value: this.filterForm.get('filterCountries').value,
        Operation: this.filterOperation,
        Property: 'Countries'
      }
      console.log(this.filtersArray)
      this.filtersArray.push(filterCountries);
    }


    this.loadUserPage();
    this.clearAllFilters();
    this.toggleDropDown('close');

}
```

Comment: check if neither `organisationField ` and `countriesField` are null in your if statements

Comment: you reset form values, thus getting null for models after reset.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara Thanks a lot, I had actually tried this before, but it was in the wrong order, the checking for null had to come first, you can put as an answer if you want

Comment: @Roy that's right, it has to be before anything, so it can't reach `trim()` function if `value` is null. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check **first** if neither of your variables are null:

```
if (organisationField.value !== null && organisationField.value.trim() == '') {
    //your code here
}

if (countriesField.value !== null && countriesField.value.trim() == '') {
    //your code here
}
```